# Why doesn't SOLR KStemFilterFactory stem the word "cards" to "card"?

Tags: solr, porter-stemmer

I am using KStem Filter Factory(KStemFF) in SOLR. I realized that the KStemFF is not 100% accurate.

Example, it does not stem the word "cards" to "card".

"sound cards" and "sound card" return different results.

Is there a way to get this working using just the KStemFF? I realized that using other stemmers like porter-stemmer may help in this case, but I really don't want to use multiple stemmers in the project.

Comment: What is the definition of the field you're using KStemFilter on?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am using simple text_en.
My field type is:
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" omitNorms="false">

My filter class is :     
    <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KStem is less aggresive than PorterStem in stemming words, and hence may skip converting certain plurals based on the rules it has.
You may want to compare few stemmers based on performance and results before making a choice. No single stemmer would provide you 100% accuracy and desired results, it has to be the MOST SUITED based on your results.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using "EngMinStem" from SOLR. This looks better than other things. To the original question, you are correct no stemmer is 100% accurate.